# AutoMapper - Map collections of different types to collection of another type with nesting

Tags: c#, collections, merge, nested, automapper

I am currently struggling with AutoMapper version 10.1.1 config.
I have the following types:

```cs
class Response
{
    List<Assignment> Assignments { get; }
    List<Product> Products { get; }
}

class Assignment
{
    int AssignmentId { get; set; }
    int ProductId { get; set; } // references Product.ProductId
}

class Product
{
    int ProductId { get; set; }
}

class AssignmentModel
{
    int AssignmentId { get; set; }
    int ProductId { get; set; }
    Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

For every item in the "Assignments" property of the response object, I would like to get a new AssignmentModel with the corresponding product based on the product id.

The current solution works by mapping the Assignments into new AssignmentModels and the Products into the existing AssignmentModels. The downside is, that I have to call the mapper twice.

```cs
cfg.CreateMap<Assignment, AssignmentModel>();
cfg.CreateMap<Product, AssignmentModel>()
    .ForMember(
        d => d.Product, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s))
    .EqualityComparison((s, d) => s.ProductId == d.ProductId)
    .ForAllOtherMembers(opt => opt.Ignore());

var assignments = mapper.Map<ICollection<AssignmentModel>>(response.Assignments);
mapper.Map(response.Products, assignments); // not using the result because it does not return assignments without products
return assignments;
```

Is it possible to do that in one call? Like so:

```cs
return mapper.Map<ICollection<AssignmentModel>>(response);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would suggest using [Custom Type Resolver](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-type-converters.html) for your scenario.

> Mapping Configuration / Profile

```cs
cfg.CreateMap<Assignment, AssignmentModel>();
            
cfg.CreateMap<Response, ICollection<AssignmentModel>>()
    .ConvertUsing<ResponseAssignmentModelCollectionConverter>();
```

In the Custom Type Converter:

1. `source.Assignments` Map to `List<AssignmentModel>`.
2. Use LINQ `.Join()` to join the result from *1* and `source.Products` by `ProductId`.

```cs
public class ResponseAssignmentModelCollectionConverter : ITypeConverter<Response, ICollection<AssignmentModel>>
{
    public ICollection<AssignmentModel> Convert(Response source, ICollection<AssignmentModel> destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var _mapper = context.Mapper;

        var result = _mapper.Map<List<AssignmentModel>>(source.Assignments);
        result = result.Join(source.Products, 
        a => a.ProductId, 
        b => b.ProductId, 
        (a, b) =>
        {
            a.Product = b;
            return a;
        })
        .ToList();

        return result;
    }
}
```

```cs
mapper.Map<ICollection<AssignmentModel>>(response);
```

[Sample Demo on .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YIynce)

Comment: thank you for the input! Can you think of a way to do this with basic automapper configuration e.g. without ConvertUsing? Imho this moves the double mapper call to the Converter, whereby the second mapper call is replaced by the join.

Comment: Hi, in my opinion, I don't think of any solution other than `ConvertUsing`. After you map `response.Assignments` to `List<AssignmentModel>`, you perform implementation for joining `assignmentModelList` and `response.Products`, this part actually can do without the need for AutoMapper. Just this converter wrap the logic/implementation into a class, then you can reuse with AutoMapper instead of writing the same logic in different (caller) places.